# How do I exclude first ten and last 1 li from hide() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So far I've this:

```
$(".actor ul li").not($(".actor ul li").slice(0,11)).hide();
```

I also would like to exclude last li from hide(). How would I do that? obvious answer would be to also show :last. But there should be an elegant way to do this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$(".actor ul li").not(':lt(10), :last').hide();
```

Comment: How is this better than previous answer?

Comment: @SandroDzneladze also check the jspref profiling http://jsperf.com/not-vs-concatenated-filters